# Ruby to_i method returns zero

Tags: ruby

Ruby `to_i` method is returning zero. Any idea why it returns zero instead of converting the string to integer.

```
              job_id = job_template_id[index]
               @handle.log(:info, "job_id is:  #{job_id}")
              job_id = job_id.to_i
              @handle.log(:info, "job_id 2 is:  #{job_id}")



[----] I, [2022-03-24T09:23:29.327746 #328:2aebe6eaa0a4]  INFO -- automation: Q-task_id([r382_miq_provision_1347]) <AEMethod launch_ansible_job> job_template_id is:  "39"
[----] I, [2022-03-24T09:23:29.328220 #328:2aebe6eaa0a4]  INFO -- automation: Q-task_id([r382_miq_provision_1347]) <AEMethod launch_ansible_job> job_id is:  "39"
[----] I, [2022-03-24T09:23:29.328778 #328:2aebe6eaa0a4]  INFO -- automation: Q-task_id([r382_miq_provision_1347]) <AEMethod launch_ansible_job> job_id 2 is:  0
```

job_template_id is an array.

```
job_template_id => ["39", "40"]
```

Comment: Try `@handle.log(:info, "job_id is: #{job_id.inspect}")` – using `inspect` instead of (the implicit) `to_s` will show the value the way `p` or IRB do.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `job_template_id` is `['39', '40']` rather than `['"39"', '"40"']`?

Consider this: in `irb`:

```
irb > job_id = "39"
 => "39" 
irb > puts "job_id is #{job_id}"
job_id is 39
 => nil 
irb > job_id.to_i
 => 39
```

There are no quotes in the interpolated string. However, if there are internal quotes, we see what you're seeing with both the string interpolation and the `#to_i` call:

```
irb > job_id = '"39"'
 => "\"39\"" 
irb > puts "job_id is #{job_id}"
job_id is "39"
 => nil 
irb > job_id.to_i
 => 0
```

You have extra quotes inside the elements of `job_template_id`. Perhaps you're using `#inspect` to populate `job_template_id` or maybe you're double JSON encoding. I'd have a look at the code that builds `job_template_id` and see where the extra quotes are coming from. I'd also rename `job_template_id` to `job_template_ids`; arrays should have plural names.